# Fastest way to access pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I am confused by the difference in performance between the various ways to access a pandas column.

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],columns=['a','b','c'])

In [2]: %timeit df['a']
The slowest run took 75.37 times longer than the fastest. This could
mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.12 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit df.a
The slowest run took 5.14 times longer than the fastest. This could
mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.59 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit df.loc[:,'a']
10000 loops, best of 3: 55 µs per loop
```

I understand that the last variant is slower because it enables the values to be set, not just accessed. But why is `df.a` slower than `df['a']`? This seems true regardless of the intermediate results being cached.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30250361/8201433) is a link that explains what is a difference between a `.` access and `[]` access.

Also look into the behavior of these operators in the documentation

[**getitem**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) (for `[]`) and [**getattr**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__)  (for `.`) methods.

`.` seems to access the column through a function call, thereby taking less time than a `[]` which is accessed as a dictionary key-value

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. However, in the pandas case the function call `.` takes twice as long as  `[]`, contrary to what you suggest. Any ideas?